# Trying to use DISTINCT but not it is not eliminating duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get distinct shipAddress1 from the query below. But it is returning me shipAddress1 with duplicates. What I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Orders.ShipAddress1,
  Orders.ShipAddress2,
  Orders.ShipCity,
  Orders.ShipState,
  Orders.ShipPostalCode,
  Customers.CustomerID,
  Customers.EmailAddress,
  Orders.OrderDate
FROM
  Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate > '04/10/2014 00:00:00' AND
GROUP BY
  Customers.CustomerID,
  Orders.ShipAddress1,
  Customers.EmailAddress,
  Orders.ShipAddress2,
  Orders.ShipCity,
  Orders.ShipState,
  Orders.ShipPostalCode,
  Orders.OrderDate
```

Comment: Combining `GROUP BY` with `DISTINCT` probably isn't good...  Choose one or the other.

Comment: All capital nicks don't seem very well on the first spot, I suggest to become simply "Queen".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that distinct is going to return distinct sets of all of those values. If shipAddress1 is the same but other columns are different, you are going to get both sets of data. Your query either needs to be changed to not involve all of those different options if you want shipAddress1's values to all be distinct.

Comment: Yeah you are right that is why it is returning me all values but if you can help me with What changes should i made to my query? I am new to sql and got stuck with that.

Comment: The problem is that it is not clear what you want. Since there are multiple entries with the same shipAddress1, which of them do you want? I can help you rewrite the query but you have to know which of the results with shipAddress1 that you actually want.

Comment: I want Orders.ShipAddress1 ,
Orders.ShipCity,
Orders.ShipState,
Orders.ShipPostalCode,
Customers.CustomerID,
Customers.EmailAddress,
Orders.OrderDate

Comment: in my final query and shipaddress1 should have all distinct addresses

Comment: What you're asking for fundamentally doesn't make sense. If there are multiple entries with different values, then how would you choose which to pick is what I'm asking. I can clearly see what columns you want, but let's say there are two different entires each with the shipAddress1 of "7 Wallabe Lane" but totally different other values. How do I choose which entry to pick? What is it ordered by? Do you want the most recent? The one with the alphabetically first email address? You need to decide in order to refine your query.